# Мне надо создать название объекта класса из двух строк. Можно ли это как-то реализовать в Python 3.7?

Tags: python-3.x

```
for i in range(5):
    unit_ + str(i+1) = Units() #Пробую чтото сделать
```

Есть цикл for. Каждый раз надо создавать объект класса Units() с новым именем из 2 строк. Как это осуществить?

Comment: Не нужно пытаться слепить имя переменной из кусков (это возможно, но не нужно). Просто используйте списки.

Comment: Что значит "объект класса из двух строк"? Что конкретно вам надо? Что вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: @fedotsoldier, уже изменил. Имелось ввиду образовать имя объекта из 2 строк.

Comment: Мой ответ всё равно вам подойдет) Если вы работаете с группой объектов не обязательно задавать им имя, создавайте их анонимно.
Для построения максимально понятного вопроса вы можете описать зачем вам это надо, тогда вам помогут решить вашу задачу без таких извращений, как создание имен переменных в цикле

Comment: Мне безмерно приятно, что мой ответ вам помог, но по-моему конкретно на ваш вопрос отлично ответил пользователь `Pavel Durmanov`, а я лишь подсказал как решить возникшую проблему другим способом. Мне кажется именно его вариант заслуживает метки правильного ответа :)

Comment: Учту ваше пожелание).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [7]: globals().update({"hello" + "world": 123})

In [8]: helloworld
Out[8]: 123
```

`globals()` возвращает словарь в котором перечислены все переменные/функции и тд на глобальном уровне.

Есть также `locals()`, возвращает словарь всего что объявлено в локальном скоупе, например в функции.

Из документации:

> Return a dictionary representing the current global symbol table. This
>   is always the dictionary of the current module (inside a function or
>   method, this is the module where it is defined, not the module from
>   which it is called).

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ. Но мне бы хотелось понять, что происходит в этом коде. Назовите пожалуйста что мне надо изучить, чтобы это понять.

Comment: @ВладимирПолихатко дополнил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Необязательно для каждого объекта создавать отдельное имя. Если вам надо создать группу объектов, вы можете создать их в цикле и сохранить в список:

```py
my_objects = list()
for i in range(10):
    my_objects.append(MyClass())  # Каждый раз будет создаваться новый объект `MyClass`
```

Дальше вы сможете обратиться к каждому из созданных объектов отдельно в цикле `for`

```py
for obj in my_objects:
    # Делайте что-то с переменной `obj`
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам может помочь `exec()`. Но использовать эту функцию рекомендуется только если Вы точно уверены в корректности передаваемых в неё команд. Хотя знаете..., вообще то не рекомендуется :)

***Пример:***

```py
name = ['spam', 'eggs', 'Ni!']

for i in range(2):
    cmd = 'var{} = "{}"'.format(i, name[i])
    exec(cmd)

print(var0)
print(var1)
print(var2)
```

*stdout:*

```html
spam
eggs
Ni!
```